# While listening mysqli_fetch_array it shows different results for the same row

Tags: php, html

Im trying to list the rooms from my hotel website by showing the price, name, etc.
While listing there are two areas where I use the price of the room, the first one is showing correctly the price of the room however the second price which appears in a dashboard showing the base price * the nights is showing (in every row) the price of the FIRST row.

This is the select code (nothing special):

```
$sqlx=sprintf("Select * from quartos");
$resx=mysqli_query($ligacao,$sqlx);
```

This is the listing code:

```
    <?php
    while($regx=mysqli_fetch_array($resx)){
    ?>
    <div class="room-box">
        <form method="post">
        <div class="col-md-5 room-img" data-bg-img="<?php echo $regx['nome_doc'];?>">
            <div class="select-room-box">
                <a href="booking-2.php?id=<?php echo $regx['id'];?>">Selecione Este Quarto</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="r-sec col-md-7">
            <div class="title-box">
                <div class="title"><?php echo $regx['nome'];?></div>
                    <div class="price">
                        <div class="title">Preço :</div>
                        <div class="value"><?php echo $regx['preco'];?>€</div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#price-break-down-1" class="price-breakdown"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Lista de Preços</a>
                    <div id="price-break-down-1" class="price-breakdown-popup mfp-hide">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="title">Preço Base</div>
                                    <div class="duration">x 
                                    <?php
                                    $diff= date_diff($entrada,$saida);        
                                    echo $diff->format("%a noites");
                                    ?>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="price"><?php echo $regx['preco'];?>€</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="title">Total</div>
                                    <div class="duration"><?php echo $diff->format("%a noites")?></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="price"><?php echo $regx['preco']*$diff->format("%a noites") ;?>€</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I know that is kinda confusing but Im in a hurry and just pasted the code (And my first time posting here), the ones I has talking is `echo $regx['preco']` in the 16th line counting from the tag php.

The first `echo $regx['preco']` in the 31st counting from the tag php is showing the right price however the second one is always showing the price of the first result.

My question is why the `$regx['preco']` is showing different results in the same row

This is my list of rooms, they both have different price numbers one 90€ and one 100€ but when I open dashboard it only shows 90€ in all rows

[image: This is my list of rooms, they both have different price numbers one 90€ and one 100€ but when I open dashboard it only shows 90€ in all rows]

[image: dashboard Quarto 1]

[image: dasboard Quarto 2]

Comment: What, *exactly*, it your question?

Comment: My question is why the $regx['preco'] is showing different results in the same row

Comment: if `$regx['preco']` show the first result ? what is ... that will show the second results , i see they are all the same

Comment: This makes no sense: `$regx['preco']*$diff->format("%a noites")` You can't multiply by a string like `2 noites`.

Comment: The thing is they are all the same, because the appear multiple times but, while listing the different rows the second $reg['preco'] I mentioned is showing the price of the first row in every row dont know why.

Comment: Im just asking to exclude some simple explanations. Did you check, that the values in your database are correct and that you connect to the right database? :-)

Comment: So how I multiply the price and the night using the $diff?

Comment: Yes the values on my db are right

Comment: It should be `$regx['preco'] * $diff->format("%a")` You only want the number, not extra words.

Comment: The thing is the multiply isnt the problem, if I add prints to the post will it help?

Comment: But it should just ignore the extra word when it converts the string to a number for multiplying.

Comment: You're saying that on row 2, when it shows the total price it's not the same as base price * number of nights?

Comment: @DiogoSIlva Yes, i think it will help. Three rows should be enough :-)

Comment: You're not getting duration from `$regx`, it's the same for every row. Is that correct?

Comment: Like I show in the prints the prices are differente however the dashboard price appears 90€ in every one (90€ be the first row price)

Comment: This is not about outputting the prices in the template, everything works fine in _that_ regard. (Which you could have easily verified yourself btw., by checking the generated HTML code.) This is because you only ever get the first of those popups shown, because you created invalid HTML by using the same ID multiple times. IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, so fix that.

Comment: i agree with @CBroe

Comment: I have checked the code you have put unnecessary "X" here: x 
                                    <?php
                                    $diff= date_diff($entrada,$saida);        
                                    echo $diff->format("%a noites");
                                    ?>

Comment: That x is text btw

Comment: Ty that was the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @CBroe in the comments, your problem is caused by your generated links for the detailed prives:

```
while($regx=mysqli_fetch_array($resx)) { 
    ?>
    ...
    <a href="#price-break-down-1" class="price-breakdown">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Lista de Preços
    </a>
    <div id="price-break-down-1" class="price-breakdown-popup mfp-hide">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
    <?php 
}
```

The `href` attribute of the link and `id` propety of the `<div>` are static for all list entries. Because ids should be unique, which they are not in your case, the link searches for the first occurance of the given id and therefore always opens the price details for the first entry.

To fix that, you would need to give each entry an unique id. This can be achied by appending a number to each `id` and `href`.

```
$counter = 1;
while($regx=mysqli_fetch_array($resx)) {
    ?>
    ...
    <a href="#price-break-down-<?= $counter ?>" class="price-breakdown">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Lista de Preços
    </a>
    <div id="price-break-down-<?= $counter ?>" class="price-breakdown-popup mfp-hide">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
    <?php 
    $counter++;
}
```

If your table provides an **unique** id for each row, that should be used instead of an extra counter:

```
while($regx=mysqli_fetch_array($resx)) {
    ?>
    ...
    <a href="#price-break-down-<?= $regx['id'] ?>" class="price-breakdown">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>Lista de Preços
    </a>
    <div id="price-break-down-<?= $regx['id'] ?>" class="price-breakdown-popup mfp-hide">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
    <?php
}
```

Comment: If @Cbroe posts an answer please remind me to remove mine. OC first